# Is it possible to spawn one process per connection in Apache with mpm_winnt?

Tags: apache-2.4, process, mpm-prefork, threads

I would like to fine tune the settings of `mpm_winnt` Apache module: for each connection, it should spawn one new Apache (httpd) process.
AFAIK this is similar to what `mpm_prefork` does (which is Linux only). I know this is somehow inefficient but it's only for some tests / debugging purposes.
I have tried to change the following settings:

- ThreadsPerChild
- ThreadLimit
- MaxConnectionsPerChild

It affects maximum threads used, but only one process is spawned. Is this something hardcoded in the implementation of `mpm_winnt` ? (eg: it can only spawn one process with multiple threads).

Comment: for what reason do you want to use the configuration? I don't see here a benefit for a common business related question or environment

Comment: I already wrote it in the OP: for debugging and test purposes. I have some performance issues that occurs with mpm_prefork, mostly due to 1 process being spawn for every connection. Unfortunately mpm_prefork is Linux only and I can't easily setup such an environment. I would like to try to do the same under Windows.